# Split query with doctrine correctly

Tags: sql, performance, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a doctrine query which e.g. look like this:

```
$object = $this->createQueryBuilder('object')
    ->leftJoin('object.element', 'element')->addSelect('element')
    ->leftJoin('object.element2', 'element2')->addSelect('element2')
    ->leftJoin('object.many', 'many')->addSelect('many')
    ->leftJoin('many.element3', 'element3')->addSelect('element3')
    ->leftJoin('many.element4', 'element4')->addSelect('element4')
    ->where('object.id = 1')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleResult();
```

The real query have more joins and need a lot of memory and the db performance is not good. In native SQL I would split it and load it correctly. What I want todo is load with the first query the object and some basic joined data. This would look like this:

```
$object = $this->createQueryBuilder('object')
    ->leftJoin('object.element', 'element')->addSelect('element')
    ->leftJoin('object.element2', 'element2')->addSelect('element2')
    ->where('object.id = 1')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleResult();
```

Now I also want to load the `many`, `many.element3` and `many.element4`. In seperate query. When I just use doctrine lazy loading feature it will create a SQL query foreach but I only want this as 1 query.

I know it would be possible to set `EAGER` on that relation but I only want to `EAGER` temporarily for this query not always when somebody join the object and access it.

Answer (score 0):

Did solve my problem the following way:

In my object I did add a new set function for the collection.

```
/**
 * Set manies.
 */
public function setManies($manies)
{
    // this clear and foreach is needed to keep it as ArrayCollection so doctrine dont need for the unitofwork request the db again
    $this->manies->clear();

    foreach ($manies as $many) {
        $this->manies->add($many);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

In the repository my code look like this:

```
$object = $this->createQueryBuilder('object')
    ->leftJoin('object.element', 'element')->addSelect('element')
    ->leftJoin('object.element2', 'element2')->addSelect('element2')
    ->where('object.id = 1')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleResult();

$object->setManies($this->getEntityManager()->getRepository(Many::class)->loadByObjectId(
        $object->getId()
    ));

return $object;
```

here the function in the many repository

```
// loadByObjectId in the many repository
$manies = $this->createQueryBuilder('many')
    ->leftJoin('many.element3', 'element3')->addSelect('element3')
    ->leftJoin('many.element4', 'element4')->addSelect('element4')
    ->where('many.object = 1')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

With this the SQL is successfully splitted in multiple request. In my case instead of 60000 rows in 1 request, I only had 40 rows affected in 4 request which make the hydration of the object a lot faster.